# R how to merge dataframes in braid-like fasion

Tags: r, merge

Say I have 2 dataframes

```
dfA <- data.frame(x = rpois(10,2), y = rpois(10,2), z = rpois(10,2), q = rpois(10,2), t = rpois(10,2))
dfB <- data.frame(a = rpois(10,2), b = rpois(10,2), c = rpois(10,2), d = rpois(10,2), e = rpois(10,2))
```

with a regular `merge(dfA, dfB)` i get a dataframe with columns in the following order: x,y,z,q,t,a,b,c,d,e

How do I merge the dataframes to get a dataframe with the columns in the following order:

x,a,y,b,z,c,q,d,t,e

ie. where the first column of each dataframe is put next to each other, then the 2nd columns, then the 3rd, etc.

Comment: Try `out <- merge(dfA, dfB); out1 <- out[order(c(seq_along(dfA), seq_along(dfB)))]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to `order` based on the sequence of columns concatenated from both the datasets

```
out <- merge(dfA, dfB) 
out1 <- out[order(c(seq_along(dfA), seq_along(dfB)))]
names(out1)
#[1] "x" "a" "y" "b" "z" "c" "q" "d" "t" "e"
```

---

Or `rbind` the column names and then coerce it to `vector` to get it collapsed by the natural column order in `matrix/data.frame`

```
out1 <- out[c(rbind(names(dfA), names(dfB)))]
names(out1)
#[1] "x" "a" "y" "b" "z" "c" "q" "d" "t" "e"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following base R code:

```
dfout <- merge(dfA,dfB)[as.vector(rbind(names(dfA),names(dfB)))]
```